# Rice as staple and fish as dish?

Tags: sentence-meaning

There is one line in a Chinese poem *daofanyugeng* which means that the villagers had rice as staple and fish as cuisine for meals.

If I translate it as **Rice as staple and fish as dish**, does the meaning get across to native speakers? Here is an example of a cooked fish.
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand it. You are pairing a container and a food type.

Comment: I thought dish could mean food prepared in a particular way as part of a meal, beyond its common meaning as a flat shallow container.

Comment: it can if the context sets the meaning, but as an aphorism, it doesn't convey anything to me at first glance. Why is the fish more a part of the "dish as part of a meal"  than the rice is?

Comment: Because in China, rice can only be cooked in limited ways, we have rice because we are used to. But things such fish, pork, vegetables can be cooked in various ways and have different flavors.  One can have one of these dishes without having rice, but can hardly have rice without one of these dishes.

Comment: The staples are things you eat most of the time. The statement "rice is a staple but fish is ... " suggests to me that people eat rice most of the time but they don't eat fish very often. With "fish is a dish" it might suggest that some effort is used to cook the fish because it is special.

Comment: Rice is nice but fish is a dish...

Comment: I don't really like "fish is a dish" because anything you eat is a dish.  I think it would be easier to answer this question if you explained more about what the original line means, and what you mean by "fish as cuisine".

Answer (score 2):

In Ken Hom's *Chinese Cookery* (1984) he says

> A typical Chinese meal consists of two parts - the *fan* which is the staple grain... and the *cai* which covers the rest of the dishes: meat, poultry, fish and vegetables.

In the West, although we do have a staple starchy food such as potato with our cooked meals, we don't have a single term for the more flavoursome part of the meal. You could possibly use *relish*, although that normally refers to an 'extra' such as chutney.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can directly translate this because of a cultural difference.

In western culture, a 'staple food' is a *basic* food that may form a major part of a *diet* as a whole, but is not considered the main or major part of a *meal*. For example, in England we enjoy dishes that originate from the Indian subcontinent and East/Southeast Asia. These cuisines are almost always served with rice, but we consider these to be a *side* to the main meal. Even when foods are paired as a whole dish, it tends to be that carbohydrates take second billing (eg 'fish and chips').

In England we often refer to 'cupboard staples', meaning items that most kitchens would keep available for frequent use. This might include things such as bread, pasta, or rice, but also oils for cooking and spices or condiments might be included. Still, we would not consider any of these to be a main part of any meal - even pasta, as when British people make pasta dishes we tend to serve it in very different ratios to traditional Italian recipes.

For these reasons, "Rice as a staple and Fish as a Dish" doesn't really make sense in English. Unless there was a specific name for the cuisine you showed a picture of, I think we would probably describe it as "fish with a side of rice", or simply "fish with rice".

Note that the difference between a 'side' and a 'side dish' in most western cultures is that a 'side' is something served on the same plate as your main, whereas a 'side dish' would literally arrive in a separate dish.

Comment: A lot of UK people, including caterers, use 'accompaniments' for 'sides', and these days not all of them arrive on the main plate.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a *poem*, the key thing is to think about what connotations are being conveyed in that sentence.

For instance, if the idea is that the rice is considered to be functional but plain, and the fish is the highlight that makes it interesting, you might say:

> Plates of rice cheered up by fish

Or perhaps the emphasis is on *making something* out of the fish:

> A variety of fish dishes, served with rice

Or perhaps they have equal importance, but different *dietary purposes*:

> Rice for energy, and fish for protein

Answer (score 0):

The normal term here would be [side dish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_dish).

> a food item that accompanies the entrée or main course at a meal.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to include "as a ..." unless you need to say that the rice or fish is used in an unexpected way.  But "serving it as part of a meal" is perfectly normal.  So you can say, "Fish and rice" or "Fish with rice".  The former if you consider the fish and the rice to be equal parts of the meal, the latter if you consider the rice to be secondary.  Or you could swap the words around as required, perhaps to suggest that "rice" was the main food.

> The villagers subsisted on rice and fish.

"Subsisted" useful word, to indicate that this was their basic food, and they had little else.